# Git: Limit the scope of a specific branch

Tags: git

Is there a way to force (atleast warn) git commits for a given branch to update only a part of the repo?

For instance, assume I am working on docs on a special `update-docs` branch, and would like to make sure I don't commit some changes I made to another part of the code by mistake. I would like git to reject the commit or at least warn me that there's a change to a file outside the scope of the `docs` folder...

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can add literally any script under git hooks, but that needs to be set locally for each machine. One workaround is to add git hooks as part of your project build process

Comment: Note that this works great for preventing mistakes, but can't stop malicious actors. The pre-receive-hook (or on GitHub or similar sites, protected branches) trick can, but it's a much bigger pain to set up (which is why GitHub and similar sites give you protected branches as a sort of pre-cooked meal).

Comment: Didn't know about hooks, thanks a lot everyone :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be possible using a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

> The `pre-commit` hook is run first, before you even type in a commit message. It’s used to inspect the snapshot that’s about to be committed, to see if you’ve forgotten something, to make sure tests run, or to examine whatever you need to inspect in the code. Exiting non-zero from this hook aborts the commit, although you can bypass it with `git commit --no-verify`. You can do things like check for code style (run `lint` or something equivalent), check for trailing whitespace (the default hook does exactly this), or check for appropriate documentation on new methods.

In your case, you can look at the list of files to see whether anything outside the "docs" tree has been added for commit.

If you are collaborating with others and want to make sure other people don't push non-docs commits to the `update-docs` branch, then you can install a server side `pre-receive` or `update` hook to verify this.